# What is a pipeline in an enterprise or business context?

Tags: meaning

I've heard the term "pipeline" used in many different contexts. Now I'm trying to get some clarity on the terminology: What exactly is a "pipeline" in a corporate or business context? How is it structured, why do I need it and what value does it bring to my company?

Answer (score 2):

A pipeline is a sequence of steps or stages that are used to achieve a certain outcome.

I see you have a Stackoverflow account, so you are probably familiar with a CI/CD pipeline. The purpose is to deploy something and you have some sequence of stages to perform to achieve that. Push code, linting, run unit tests, run integration tests, pack binaries, upload to server, etc.

In a business context it's similar but it involves more abstract or broad steps.

You could have sales pipeline for example which are the stages from identifying a potential client, to engaging activities, to sales pitches, to signing the contract or closing the deal.

Project approval pipeline for example, where every project, before being implemented, needs to be approved. You could have stages for recording the idea for a new application, building a project charter, gathering feedback, sign off, prioritization, resource allocation, etc.

Hiring people is done using a HR pipeline for example. Here you could have one pipeline to actually approve and open a new position, then a separate pipeline to handle the applicants from when they submit a CV to when they are onboarded.

So in a business context, it generically means some stages for a particular activity that's being performed, stages that need to happen in a sequence, like moving them through a pipeline.

Answer (score 0):

It could mean many different things depending on context. These are the ones I can think of that are relevant to the topic of this forum.

Pipeline of projects/work: future work expected from a team or organization, especially in the case of teams acting as a shared resource and serving internal or external customers.

Sales pipeline: future new business deals that are anticipated or being sought through sales and marketing activity.

Data pipeline: the movement and processing of data between and within software systems and the technology that makes it happen.